# Antiderivative of an absolute function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration

$sgn(x)$ is the Sign-Function, $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ and $S(x) := F(x) \cdot sgn(f(x))$

$$  \int \left|f(x)\right| \, dx  =  S(x) + \left(\sum\limits_{p=1}^{q}sgn(x-z_p) \lim_{x \to z_p-}S(x)\right) $$

where $ z_1, z_2, ..., z_q$ are the real roots of $f$.

I want to show, that $S(x) + \left(\sum\limits_{p=1}^{q}sgn(x-z_p) \lim_{x \to z_p-}S(x)\right) $ is continuous, if $f$ is continuous.

Is my proof okay?

$S(x) + \left(\sum\limits_{p=1}^{q}sgn(x-z_p) \lim_{x \to z_p-}S(x)\right) $ is continuos in all sections between the $z_p$ and an antiderivative. We have to show that the function is also continuos in the $z_p$. Then it is continuous on entire $\mathbb{R}$.

We look at:
$ S(x) + \left(sgn(x-z_p) \lim_{x \to z_p-}S(x)\right) $

At first: $\lim_{x \to z_p-}S(x) = \lim_{x \to z_p-}F(x) \cdot sgn(f(x))$

$\lim_{x \to z_p-}F(x) = F(z_p)$ because $f$ is continous.

Because $z_p$ is a real root of $f$:
$\lim_{x \to z_p-}sgn(f(x)) = 1$ and $\lim_{x \to z_p+}sgn(f(x)) = -1$

or $\lim_{x \to z_p-}sgn(f(x)) = -1$ and $\lim_{x \to z_p+}sgn(f(x)) = 1$

Together:
$\lim_{x \to z_p-}S(x) = F(z_p)$ or $\lim_{x \to z_p-}S(x) = -F(z_p)$

It is always:
$\lim_{x \to z_p-}sgn(x-z_p) = -1$ and $\lim_{x \to z_p+}sgn(x-z_p) = 1$

Case 1: $\lim_{x \to z_p-}S(x) = F(z_p)$

$\lim_{x \to z_p-}\left(S(x)+sgn(x-z_p) \cdot F(z_p)\right)$
$= F(z_p) -F(z_p) = 0$

$\lim_{x \to z_p+}\left(S(x)+sgn(x-z_p) \cdot F(z_p)\right)$
$= -F(z_p) +F(z_p)) = 0$

Case 2: $\lim_{x \to z_p-}S(x) = -F(z_p)$

$\lim_{x \to z_p-}\left(S(x)-sgn(x-z_p) \cdot F(z_p)\right)$
$= -F(z_p) +F(z_p) = 0$

$\lim_{x \to z_p+}\left(S(x)-sgn(x-z_p) \cdot F(z_p)\right)$
$= F(z_p) -F(z_p) = 0$

We don't have to look at the other $q-1$ terms of the sum, because they are constant while not looking at their $z_p$.